# How to use Nokogiri in ruby to parse link contain # charater

Tags: ruby, web-crawler, nokogiri

I use Nokogiri in ruby to parse link like this

```
link='http://vnreview.vn/danh-gia-di-dong#cur=2'

doc= Nokogiri::HTML(open(link,'User-Agent'=>'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.31 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/26.0.1410.64 Safari/537.31').read, nil, 'UTF-8')
```

but `nokogiri` return doc is source of link='http://vnreview.vn/danh-gia-di-dong'
How can i parse link with `#cur=1, #cur=2...`

Comment: FYI, the part starting with # is called the _fragment_.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fragment is not sent to server with http request, i.e. if you open `http://www.example.com/#fragment` in browser following request will be made:

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: example.com
```

Then after receiving response, browser will append fragment to URL and perform some actions (for example, scroll to element with `id="fragment"`, or execute javascript callbacks)

If page content differs based on fragment, it's done via javascript. Nokogiri is not capable of running javascript, so you need some other tool, like [selenium-webdriver](http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/rb/index.html) or [capybara-webkit](http://blog.dharanasoft.com/2012/03/19/a-search-spider-in-ruby-using-capybara-webkit/).

Another option is to inspect ajax requests on page you trying to parse and probably you'll find JSON with data you need. Then download this json directly. Probably content is already on page, and it's just hidden via css (like tabs in twitter bootstrap).

Comment: On site you provided when `#cur=2` is added to url, http://vnreview.vn/danh-gia-di-dong/-/article_summary/iZQ8/15/0/2 is loaded via ajax. `#cur=3` loads http://vnreview.vn/danh-gia-di-dong/-/article_summary/iZQ8/15/0/3 and so on.

Comment: how can you find from #cur=2 to http://vnreview.vn/danh-gia-di-dong/-/article_summary/iZQ8/15/0/2

Comment: Open http://vnreview.vn/danh-gia-di-dong in google chrome, then open developer tools (`cmd+option+i` on mac, `ctrl+shift+i` on win/linux), then open `network` tab, clear requests log (2nd button under tabs bar, one with crossed circle). Then click "Tiếp theo" link on page you opened. Requests tab will be filled with lots of data. Top request will be the one you are looking for.